# Double click on folders opens VSCode

Tags: 20.04, directory, lts

In a recently upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS, when we try to open a directory with double click on it, the system opens the VSCode, but I don't know why.

How can set a different "open with" to directories?

Anyone have some clue about this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been getting this since I installed vscode in Ubuntu 19.10 too. When I click on a link to my Downloads folder within the Gnome settings (Bluetooth settings) panel it opens up in vscode instead of my file manager. This appears to be due to an overzealous association of vscode with plain text and directory mime types.

I resolved this as follows:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
```

Then comment out the following line by placing a hash in front

```
# MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;
```

Then update the application database

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

Be warned that this change may need to be reapplied the next time you update vscode.

Comment: Thank you very much @whistler!!!!

Comment: Please note that you don't need to comment out the whole line, but simply delete the 'inode/directory;' part.